# При запуске ./vendor/bin/sail up есть строка laravel.test Error

Tags: php, laravel

После того как скачал laravel проект и запускаю sail up идет загрузка необходимых компонентов и во время это загрузки висит строка laravel.test Error. Установка продолжается, Всё качается и устанавливается и завершается успешно, просто эта строка не дает мне покоя, почему она есть, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема Pear/PECL. Библиотека PEAR, включенная в дистрибутив Ubuntu, очень старая. Чтобы исправить это, убедитесь, что у вас установлена последняя версия.

Добавьте это в файл Dockerfile после блока PHP:

```
&& wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar \
&& php go-pear.phar \
&& pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
```

или может быть из-за места на диске с Docker.

```
docker system prune --force
```

или это связано с тем, что вы удалили свой созданный образ или ваш созданный образ laravel.test был поврежден

```
sail build или ./vendor/bin/sail build
sail up
```

Comment: У меня нет файла dockerfile